# Uploading pictures python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am completely new to Python and I'm trying to learn how to build GUI's for my business to help automate some of my work. I'm trying to upload a jpeg to the app I'm making, but I keep getting the same error code. Here it is along with my code beneath it:

```
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\Users\samuel baker\Desktop\Yo3Updated140_Orthomosaic_export_SunJun14164005.937211.jpg
```

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

image = ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()

myCanvas = Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="skyblue")
myCanvas.pack()

myFrame = Frame(root, height=450, width=450, bg="pink")
myFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

my_Image = PhotoImage(image, file="C:\\Users\\samuel baker\\Desktop\\Yo3Updated140_Orthomosaic_export_SunJun14164005.937211.jpg")
Canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=my_Image)

myLabel = Label(root, text="Hi Sam", fg="gold", bg="White", padx="25", pady="20", font=('Courier New', 30))
myLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You used Python built-in `PhotoImage()` which does not support JPEG image.

Change

```
my_Image = PhotoImage(image, file=...)
```

to

```
my_Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=...)`
```

Also the following line

```
Canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=my_Image)
```

should be

```
myCanvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=my_Image)
```

---

PS: I think the line `image = Image, ImageTk` is a typo and so remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Python's built in `PhotoImage` function cannot import a JPEG image. Try using

```
my_Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(•••)
```

Instead of

```
my_Image = PhotoImage(•••)
```

Comment: If `tk` is the alias name of `tkinter` module, then `tk.PhotoImage(...)` is the built-in `PhotoImage` as well.